# Android Studio Room Database

Tags: java, android-room

Hello I am developing a mobile application in android studio and I am using the room database. I have a problem like this. I want all the data in the database to be deleted 1 month after the user starts using the application. how can I do it?

For example, after the end of March, the database should be reset and the entered data should be made again

Comment: This isn't Room specific, you need to use WorkManager. You need to set a task that will run at a specific time/date etc

Comment: Workmanager is the best solution for you. Set a task at your desired date/time, on that task you can delete all the data from your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timestamp. Then invoke a delete all rows in all tables whenever the database is first accessed and the timestamp is one month. Followed by resetting the timestamp.

This could be invisible, bar the loss of the data.

Perhaps consider the following demonstration:-

The core table (or tables if need be):-

```
@Entity
class Table1 {
   @PrimaryKey
   Long table1Id=null;
   String somedata;

   Table1(){}
   @Ignore
   Table1(String somedata) {
      this.somedata=somedata;
   }
}
```

The table for the timestamp that controls the deletions:-

```
@Entity
class Control {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long delete_control=System.currentTimeMillis() / MainActivity.DROP_MILLISECONDS;
}
```

- DROP_MILLISECONDS equates to 1000 (this suits SQLite better)

The `@Dao` abstract class (could be an interface instead):-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDAOs {
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   abstract long insert(Table1 table1);
   
   /*<<<<<<<<<< ONLY FOR THE DEMO TO JUMP 1 MONTH >>>>>>>>>>*/
   @Query("UPDATE control SET delete_control = strftime('%s',delete_control,'unixepoch','-1 month');")
   abstract void  alterDeleteControl();
}
```

The `@Database` annotated abstract class, where the time triggered work is undertaken:-

```
@Database(entities = {Control.class,Table1.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDAOs getAllDAOs();

    private static TheDatabase instance;
    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of the demo */
                    .addCallback(cb) /*<<<<<<<<<< see code below >>>>>>>>>>*/
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /* The Call back i.e. the handler */
    static Callback cb = new Callback() {

        /* the onOpen method is passed control whenever the database is first accessed, so whenever the App runs */
        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            Log.d("DBINFO","onOpen Called");
            /* If not in a transaction then use a transaction */
            boolean transactionStarted = false;
            if (!db.inTransaction()) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","onOpen - beginning transaction.");
                db.beginTransaction();
                transactionStarted = true;
            }
            /* Check to see if the deletions are to be done */
            /* If so then delete all rows  and importantly set the timestamp to now */
            if (isControlToBeActivated(db)) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","onOpen - Delete Control Activated");
                db.delete("table1",null,null);
                Log.d("DBINFO","onOpen - Deleted all rows from table1.");
                /* and more tables if necessary */
                Log.d("DBINFO","onOpen - beginning transaction.");
                db.execSQL("UPDATE control  SET delete_control = ?;",new String[]{ String.valueOf (System.currentTimeMillis()/MainActivity.DROP_MILLISECONDS)});
            }
            /* if it was not in a transaction then end the transaction applying the changes */
            if (transactionStarted) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","onOpen - committing and ending transaction.");
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();
                transactionStarted = false;
            }
        }

        /* the onCreate method is passed control ONCE in the lifetime of the database */
        /* so add the timestamp here */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            long result;
            Log.d("DBINFO","onCreate Called - Inserting delete_control row");
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("delete_control",System.currentTimeMillis() / MainActivity.DROP_MILLISECONDS);
            result = db.insert("control", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE,cv);
            Log.d("DBINFO","onCreate Complete - result (rowid of inserted row) is " + String.valueOf(result));
        }
    };

    /* Checks to see if the timestamp is a month old or older */
    private static boolean isControlToBeActivated(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        long dateNow = System.currentTimeMillis() / MainActivity.DROP_MILLISECONDS;
        boolean flag = false;
        Cursor csr = db.query("SELECT (date(delete_control,'unixepoch',?)) <= date('now') FROM control",new String[]{MainActivity.DATA_DELETE_CONTROL});
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","isControlToBeActivated extracted a row. The result being " + csr.getString(0));
            flag = (csr.getInt(0) != 0);
        }
        csr.close();
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Finally, to demonstrate some Activity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String DATA_DELETE_CONTROL = "+1 month";
    public static final long DROP_MILLISECONDS = 1000;

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDAOs dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDAOs();
        dao.insert(new Table1("The first data"));
        dao.insert(new Table1("Some more data"));
        dao.insert(new Table1("And even more data"));

        dao.alterDeleteControl(); /* would not be used normally (moves the timestamp back 1 month ready for next time App is run) */

    }
}
```

- So when first run the database will be created, when the attempt is made to insert the 3 rows.
- As the database is created the overidden **onCreate** method in the callback is invoked and the timestamp is populated with the current datetime (time part is largely ignored).
- eventually Room will then insert the 3 rows into table1
- to make the next run act as if the data is old, the timestamp is altered by moving it back 1 month.

The App has the following output in the Log for this first run:-

```
2023-03-02 12:25:23.926 D/DBINFO: onCreate Called - Inserting delete_control row
2023-03-02 12:25:23.926 D/DBINFO: onCreate Complete - result (rowid of inserted row) is 1677720323
2023-03-02 12:25:23.932 D/DBINFO: onOpen Called
2023-03-02 12:25:23.932 D/DBINFO: onOpen - beginning transaction.
2023-03-02 12:25:23.934 D/DBINFO: isControlToBeActivated extracted a row. The result being 0
2023-03-02 12:25:23.934 D/DBINFO: onOpen - committing and ending transaction.
```

- i.e. onCreate was called as expected, as was onOpen
- the timestamp was set to 1677720323 (the datetime when run as a long)
- The check made by onOpen returned false (0) so no deletions were attemmtped.

Importantly though (for the demo) is the value of the timestamp Using App Inspection:-
[image]

- Query run to show the actual value, the date of actual value (i.e. 1 month ago) and the date of original value inserted (i.e. the current date).

If the App is then rerun the log now shows:-

```
2023-03-02 12:39:04.840 D/DBINFO: onOpen Called
2023-03-02 12:39:04.840 D/DBINFO: onOpen - beginning transaction.
2023-03-02 12:39:04.842 D/DBINFO: isControlToBeActivated extracted a row. The result being 1
2023-03-02 12:39:04.842 D/DBINFO: onOpen - Delete Control Activated
2023-03-02 12:39:04.843 D/DBINFO: onOpen - Deleted all rows from table1.
2023-03-02 12:39:04.843 D/DBINFO: onOpen - beginning transaction.
2023-03-02 12:39:04.844 D/DBINFO: onOpen - committing and ending transaction.
```

- i.e. onCreate was not invoked as the database exists
- onOpen is invoked AND due to the altered timestamp (only altered to demonstrate) now being a month ago the check result is true (1) and the rows are deleted from the table. Furthermore and importantly, the timestamp is changed to the current datetime ready for the next month. (however the activity code then alters it to a month ago).

  - the line `//dao.alterDeleteControl();` should really be removed. As should the Logging.